# Make Assembly Load Options unique to each assembly in Siemens NX 12

Tags: cad, modeling, software

I have a few assemblies I'm working on. For the most part, each assembly is self-contained in its own folder (assembly file and part files). However, there are a number of common parts that are stored in their own separate folder. When I import these into my assemblies using the Add Component feature, it works fine. However, once I closed the assembly and opened it back up, the common parts were not found and not loaded. I did some Bing-ing and ended up changing the Assembly Part Options so that the assembly folder and the various folders I saved common parts to were all listed under "From Search Folders". That works great, as long as I'm only ever working on that assembly. However, when I opened another assembly again, I noticed that that one also had the same issue. I figured no problem, I'll just do the same thing. When I went to do that, I discovered that the Assembly Load Options paths were by default the same I had set for the first assembly. Is there a way of having these path lists be unique to certain assemblies? I don't want to have to add a new folder to this list every time I make a new assembly and eventually end up with some insanely long path list.

Thanks!

Comment: If might help those who might be able to help you to specify the software you are using. It might be something related to that particular software, or it might be how its been configured.

Comment: @Fred, thanks for the feedback. I'm happy to give software specifications. Which would be useful, beyond the fact that it's NX 12?